# Retrieving information with POST method using PHP

Tags: php, forms, shopping-cart

I am trying to send product quantity from product.php to cart.php.

```
 <form id="form1" name="form1" method="POST" action="cart.php">
    <input type="hidden" name="pid" id="pid" value="<?php echo $id; ?>" />
    <!--<input type="text" name="qnty" id="qnty"/>-->
   <select name="qnty">
    <option></option><option>5</option><option>6</option><option>7</option><option>8</option><option>9</option><option>10</option><option>11</option><option>12</option><option>13</option><option>14</option><option>15</option><option>20</option><option>25</option><option>30</option><option>40</option><option>50</option><option>60</option><option>70</option><option>80</option><option>90</option><option>100</option><option>150</option><option>200</option><option>300</option></select>

    <input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Add to Shopping Cart" />
  </form>
```

Then I am trying to retrieve the value of qnty in cart.php by using:

```
if(isset($_POST['qnty']) )
{
  $qnty = $_POST['qnty'];
}
echo $qnty
```

However i am getting an undefined variable error message. It worked fine when i submitted the form to product.php but not to cart.php. Anyone know where im going wrong?

Comment: Try print_r($_POST). It will print the entire content of the $_POST array. If the data is not there, you're looking in the wrong location.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php

Comment: thanks that is returning "Array ( )", when you say looking in the wrong location how do you mean?

Comment: Apparently, your $_POST array is empty. Try print_r($_REQUEST) to see the full http request (hopefully including your parameters). http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.request.php

Answer (score 0):

It is because you need to declare the variable, or else it will show like this

```
Notice: Undefined variable: id in C:\xampp\htdocs\amazon\test.php on line 9
```

Answer (score 0):

either print `$qnty` inside the if loop or declare `$qnty=0` before the if loop.

in your case, if `qnty` is not set, it will give undefined variable `$qnty`.

Comment: thanks i have tried print_r($_POST), and it is returning Array ( )?